# Waterproofing plywood for a tub surround?

Tags: bathroom, plywood, sealant, finish

I'm looking at replacing my bath surround as the original MDF version has swollen and split. Since bath panels are expensive, I have a full sheet of 18mm plywood perfect for the job. I plan on adding some nice trim and painting it.

What is the best way to waterproof this sheet to allow it to survive long term moisture/humidity from the shower? Naturally it won't be getting covered in water but the way the old sheet of MDF has reacted it wouldn't hurt to be safe.

Comment: Don't do it.  Use some sort of cement or other water resistant backer board.

Comment: This Bath panel. Where is it located and what does it do?

Comment: @delphicoracle It's the panel that goes around the side of the tub for finishing/aesthetic purposes but is regularly subject to water trickling down the side from the shower spilling out

Comment: "Bath panels are expensive". But waterproofing MDF and/or plywood and replacing every year or two isn't?

Comment: @FreeMan In the UK most of these Bath panels are made out of MDF already. I already have a sheet of Plywood so there is no harm in asking the question. If you don't think it's viable, then I welcome your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the 18mm is exterior grade, you can do this provided that you fill in the edges and paint all six sides of the sheet with primer and two coats of paint to get proper color depth. Put a top coat of water based polyurethane in the sheen of your choice on all faces and edges to add additional waterproofing. You may need to fill and sand the good side to get the surface you want.
Alternatively, use the plywood as a base, seal the edges and cement a colored 1/8" acrylic sheet to it for your finished side.